# Enabling mhchem to write chemical formulas?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, mathjax

It would be nice to have `mhchem` enabled, by adding

```
TeX: {
  extensions: ["mhchem.js"]
}
```

to the mathjax configuration. This would be useful to write chemical reactions.

Comment: related: [siunitx LaTeX package?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/siunitx-latex-package).

Comment: FWIW, [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+mhchem)'s the related entries on Chemistry.SE.

Comment: The siunitx package is not part of the standard mathjax distro: enabling mhchem is just a one-line change. I can't even understand why this would cause a debate. Bandwidth?

Comment: For those of us who don't use `mhchem` it would be nice to have a link to a summary of what it is and how it works. Even the official LateX package documentation if the MathJax implementation adheres well.

Comment: This may be the link I wanted: https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/

Comment: You can, of course, use `\require{mhchem}` in order to load mhchem as a one-off for the answer you are writing.  E.g., `$\require{mhchem} \ce{H20}$`.  You only need to use `\require{mhchem}` once on the page.

Comment: @DavideCervone I was not aware of that. Nice there is a workaround.

Comment: @DavideCervone Hi. `$\require{mhchem}$` loads the chemistry package, but `$\require{physics}$` doesn't seem to load the physics package. For instance, `$\require{physics}\dv[n]{f}{x}$` doesn't render. Any idea why?

Comment: For security reasons, `\require{}` only loads extensions that are in the core MathJax distribution.  The `mhchem` extension is there because I did a version of it some time ago, but the physics extension is a third-party extension.  So it can't be loaded in that way unless the site sets it up specifically to allow that, which is not the case here.

Comment: @DavideCervone Gotcha. Thanks for the response! :)

Answer (score 4):

I've marked this as [status-deferred](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred) since it [recently came up again](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13118/44126) after three years of minimal activity and interest.  If someone wants this feature, let's have a fresh thread about it.