# Are there any special packages enabled for MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I usually hang out at ChemistrySE, where I use \ce{} to format chemical equations. I once tried to use \ce{} here to write a nuclear reaction, and was perplexed when it didn't work. Someone told me that mhchem isn't enabled here. I ended up having to use \text{} instead.

So, are there any special packages for MathJax here? Or is it just plain old MathJax just like how it's at MathSE?

Comment: relevant: [Enabling mhchem?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10069).

Comment: From AccidentalFourierTransform's link: "You can, of course, use `\require{mhchem}` in order to load mhchem as a one-off for the answer you are writing. E.g., `$\require{mhchem} \ce{H20}$`. You only need to use `\require{mhchem}` once on the page."

Comment: @heather This is good. I'll try this out now.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are no packages automatically enabled on this site. The community is of the opinion that none of the available packages would be widely useful enough to justify enabling them by default (although there is [an ongoing discussion about mhchem](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10069)).

Comment: Thanks for finding that link, but I wouldn't call that an "ongoing discussion". Basically nothing has been discussed at all in that post (no answers, very little attention and votes).

Comment: It wasn't me, it was AccidentalFourierTransform who found it, in the comments on the question. Anyway there is a discussion in the comments there, and the matter isn't yet resolved, hence "ongoing" (just not active)

Comment: @Pritt there was a good bit of discussion over mhchem in chat, as I recall.