# Using chemical formulas

Tags: support, feature-request, mathjax

#### Using chemical formulas

I've tried using, now be careful: dollar-sign backslash letter "ce" opening-brace chemical-formula closing-brace dollar-sign.

Unlike on *[Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour)*, it is not working here. Did I make some mistake, is it working differently here or not supported at all?

Comment: *"[The mhchem extension has been enabled for chemistry.se](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/which-plugins-for-chemical-formulas-do-we-need/2#comment44_2)"*. [More officially](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/enable-mhchem-mathjax-extension).

Comment: An example: `$\ce{H2O}$`

Comment: @PeterMortensen I've tried, but it doesn't work. (https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/579355/102232)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$\ce$` command is provided by the [mhchem package](https://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem?lang=en), which is [available in MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/mhchem.html)
but [currently not loaded by default](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10069/44126) on Physics or Physics Meta.

A workaround is to use `$\require{mhchem}$` somewhere in the question or answer where you need it, e.g.

$$
\require{mhchem}
\ce{np->d\gamma}
$$

Note that, since 2019, statements like `\require` are [local to questions and answers, rather than global to the page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29621/166791), so you’ll have to include this require statement explicitly in each question or answer where you want it.