# Feature suggest writing chemical elements on Physics.SE

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

On occasion, questions / answers / comments on physics.se deal with chemical elements. An example  for this may be to discern between the isotopes of carbon, C-12, C-13, and C-14.  I would like to suggest an expansion of the acceptable syntax to write, e.g., $^{12}\mathrm{C}$.  At present, I know `$^{12}\mathrm{C}$` yields a visually reasonable result, but there may be more efficient approaches (by the number of key strokes) that I'm not yet aware off.

On chemistry.se, this problem was solved by adding [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) to the "vocabulary" of mathJax.   For the isotope mentioned above, the syntax would then simplify to a shorter input of `$\ce{^{12}C}$`.

Additional benefits potentially relevant to the audience of physics.se could be

- the easier input of chemical sum formulae.  To write e.g., about water, $\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O}$ (please, not a mixed roman / italic $H_2O$ as obtained by `$H_2O$`), the input would be shortened to `$\ce{H2O}$` instead of the more verbose `$\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O}$`.
- Describing recorded measurements like "13 kg", currently entered either as-such in plain text, or formatted `$13~\mathrm{kg}$` would be just `$\pu{13 kg}$`.

  The syntax permitted on chemistry.se equally allows an input of `$\pu{-17.3 ^\circ{}C}$` to yield $-17.3~^\circ{}\mathrm{C}$; to arrive at the same here on physics.se, I type as `$-17.3~^\circ{}\mathrm{C}$`.  The later demands more attention to detail.

Because `mhchem` brings something special to `mathJax` not all web browsers understand (well enough) when providing a table of contents about current questions, chemistry.se established the rule to constrain the use of `mhchem` to *the body* of questions, answers, comments.  So, it is not the panacea for all formatting issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling mhchem to write chemical formulas?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10069/)

Comment: @JohnRennie The page mentioned by you does answer the question.  Apparently, chem.se's `\pu` instruction is of some different origin, but I'm fine to close the question.

Comment: no thanks.${}{}$