# Apparently incomplete support of mhchem on Physics

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, mathjax, software-questions

$\require{mhchem}$

Inspired by a question on [chemistry.se](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/175914/) (now closed, because it was a cross post from [Phys.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/778114/)), I observe the [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) extension can be used here provided the question/answer contains once `$\require{mhchem}$`*  to render e.g., `\ce{C6H12O6}` (sum formula of e.g. glucose) as $\ce{C6H12O6}$.

In the current second version, the post includes, e.g.,

$$\epsilon_n = 1.775\times10^{-20}\,\text{J}$$

the OP currently defines by `$$\epsilon_n = 1.775\times10^{-20}\,\text{J}$$`.  With mhchem's `\pu{}` command (physical units) on *[Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour)* requires `$$\epsilon \pu{1.775E-20 J}$$` only.  Here on *[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)*, the resulting $$\epsilon \pu{1.775E-20 J}$$ suggests some support is missing.  At present, the nested application `$\ce{\pu{3 kg}}$` does not work fully either ($\ce{\pu{3 kg}}$).

Questions:

- is this an issue the moderators of *Physics* may address to the maintainers of Stack Exchange?
- alternatively, is the use of a different (perhaps more siunitx like) approach more suitable here on *Physics*?

* As recommended both by [the author](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) and comments on *[Meta Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/)* [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/enabling-mhchem-to-write-chemical-formulas).  It is engaged.

Comment: I've been answering questions on this site for 10 years and I don't think I've ever once anything other than vanilla Mathjax. I only see [43 instances](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=mhchem) of mhchem in the post out of a total of >220k questions & ??? answers. I guess it seems to me that none of this is needed?

Comment: @KyleKanos Speculation: perhaps the use of symbols in italics, and (upright) units (with proper, non-breaking space) is less frequent in a typical question on physics, than for  (more homework like) questions about physical chemistry on Chemistry (where dimension analysis is/should be used) because questions here on Physics address problems more on a conceptual perspective.

Comment: My point was that less than 0.008% of all posts (226k questions, 330k posts) on this site have ever used mhchem, so I'm not sure that this qualifies as a problem that needs fixing or even cursory looks.

Comment: @KyleKanos With this background, I'm fine to accept mhchem is not a tool this significant on *Physics* as it is on *Chemistry*.  Case closed.

Comment: @Buttonwood It looks like we don't have the mchem extension isn't enabled by default on Physics. Enabling it might resolve it. But typically, we like to see a more formal request to turn that on for a site. [It looks like there was a conversation before](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10069/311812), but we might need a fresh ask on that to ensure people can weigh in.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is any movement on this anywhere, so I am removing the tag and leaving it declined. Feel free to add the tag back on a new request if there is sufficient community support.

Comment: @SpencerG It is an application the audience here (physics) does not perceive as much as an advantage as the audience on chemistry.  When filing the question, I was not aware how big (or perhaps better: how small) this niche here on physics is.  Now that I know better, it is a *when in Rome, do as the Romans do* which, without regret, is fine.